# Combining 2 lists of lists in python

Tags: python, list, merge, sublist

I am newbie in python. I need to merge 2 lists of lists based on the first element in each list. Here are the lists:

```
first_list = [['aaa', 551, 10972],
              ['bbb', 552, 10872],
              ['ccc', 553, 11103],
              ['ddd', 554, 10912]]

second_list = [['aaa', 240], 
               ['bbb', 120], 
               ['ccc', 325], 
               ['ddd', 270]]
```

The code I have written:

```
join_list = []
for x in range(0, len(first_list)):
    temp = [first_list[x], second_list[x][1]]
    join_list.append(temp)
```

The following is the output:

```
join_list =
[[['aaa', 551, 10972], 240],
 [['bbb', 552, 10872], 120],
 [['ccc', 553, 11103], 325],
 [['ddd', 554, 10912], 270]]
```

I need to flatten the list of the list in each element in `join_list`, e.g the first element in `join_list[0] = ['histogram', 551, 10972, 240]`.
Also, if the order of the second list is change and if there is an addition of a sublist in the first element, the 2 lists is still can be merged based on the first index in each element. So, it works like the VLOOKUP or HLOOKUP in Ms.Excel. How can we do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way which does not assume a specific ordering of either list.

```
d = dict(second_list)

res = [i + [d[i[0]]] for i in first_list]

[['aaa', 551, 10972, 240],
 ['bbb', 552, 10872, 120],
 ['ccc', 553, 11103, 325],
 ['ddd', 554, 10912, 270]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could introduce `lookup` dict and set default value in case there is no match:

```
lookup = dict(second_list)
default = 0
join_list = [i + [lookup.get(i[0], default)] for i in first_list]
```

Here, default is set to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `chain` from `itertools` to flatten

**Demo:**

```
first_list = [['aaa', 551, 10972],
              ['bbb', 552, 10872],
              ['ccc', 553, 11103],
              ['ddd', 554, 10912]]

second_list = [['aaa', 240], 
               ['bbb', 120], 
               ['ccc', 325], 
               ['ddd', 270]]

from itertools import chain
print([list(chain(*[v, [second_list[i][1]]])) for i, v in enumerate(first_list)])
```

**Output:**

```
[['aaa', 551, 10972, 240], ['bbb', 552, 10872, 120], ['ccc', 553, 11103, 325], ['ddd', 554, 10912, 270]]
```

Comment: What's the difference between your output and mine? I need them to be flattened. And is it possible to merge them if the order of the second_list is changed?

Comment: Sorry mis-understood your que

Comment: You can use `chain` from `itertools` to flatten.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
d = dict(second_list)
flat = [a+[d[a[0]]] for a in first_list]
```

It gives me:

```
flat = [['aaa', 551, 10972, 240],
 ['bbb', 552, 10872, 120],
 ['ccc', 553, 11103, 325],
 ['ddd', 554, 10912, 270]]
```

This way the order of your second list does not matter.